# MYSQL special Char

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in my table this value ART(\'O\') in the field Subject.

How do I check if this subject exist?

I tried:

```
select * from table1 where Subject = 'ART(\'O\')';

select * from table1 where Subject = "ART(\'O\')";
```

Both failed at picking up the record.

How sholud I prhase the query so that the record containing ART(\'O\') will be picked?
Note: Please do not refer the query: select * from table1 where Subject like '%ART(%';
bec they may be other records such as ART(EX), ART(NA),etc... existing

Need to know how to use the Subject = '' method. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value contains the backslashes, you probably need to escape them. Otherwise you're looking for value `ART('O')`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Subject = "ART(\\'O\\')";
```

Also make sure you don't have trailing whitespace.